# TLP or Default Power Management, on Dell Latitude E6430 laptop?

Tags: tlp

I have a Dell Latitude E6430 laptop. I just installed tlp:

```
sudo apt install tlp cpufrequtils
```

This worked successfully.  I then entered:

```
sudo systemctl enable tlp.service
```

This produced the error message,

```
Synchronizing state of tlp.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable tlp
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/tlp.service is masked.
```

I COULD unmask tlp.service; but should I do this?  The fact that tlp,service is masked suggests on the architecture of this Dell Latitude, the system power management is better?

I'd appreciate advice on which is best on this architecture.